# Durrett's Probability: Theorem 6.2.6

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory, stationary-processes, equidistribution

I am having some difficulty understanding the concept of *measure preserving*, *invariance*, and *ergodic*.

Here is a proof from Theorem 6.2.6 in Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples, 5e* (p.338) (available at [https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/pte.html)), which states that **If A = [a, b), then the exceptional set is $\emptyset$**. Here the $\varphi$ is a measure-preserving transformation, and $A_k = [a + 1/k, b-1/k)$.

I am trying to understand two points:

1. Why do we need to show that $G$ is dense in $[0, 1)$?
2. Why does $\varphi^m \omega_k \in A_k$ imply $\varphi^m x \in A$ if $x \in [0, 1)$, $\omega_k \in G$, with $|\omega_k - x| < 1/k$? My guess is that this has something to do with the measure-preserving property of $\varphi$ or the invariance of $A$ or $A_k$ (if they are), but I am not sure where and how exactly these concepts were used in this context.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\phi$ is not any invariant function with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1)$, but a translation:
$$\phi(x)=x+\theta\mod1$$
for some $\theta\in[0,1)$.

1. It is not that one has to prove that $G$ is dense. The strategy that Rick Durrett set out is to first construct a set $G$ that is large (full measure) in $[0,1)$ where the result of the ergodic theorem holds for each open interval $A_k=(a+1/k,b-1/k)$ at any point of $G$ $(k>2/(b-a), k\in\mathbb{N}$. The fact that $P[G]=1$ implies that $G$ is dense in $[0,\infty)$ (otherwise there is a point $x\in [0,1)$ and a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ in $[0,1)$ of radius $\delta>0$ such that $V\cap G=\emptyset$. This would imply that $P[G]=P[G\cap V]+P[G\setminus V]\leq 1-\varepsilon<1$, contradicting the fact that $P[G]=1$.

The remaining of the proof consists on  letting the ergodic averages operate on points in $[0,1)\setminus G$. As $G$ is dense, you get  almost the same as operating on points in $G$.

2. For all $k>\frac{2}{b-a}$ set $A_k=(a+1/k,b-1/k)$. If $x\in [0,1)\setminus G$, by density, there are points $\omega_k\in G$ such that $|x-\omega_k|<\frac1k$. Since $S_n\mathbb{1}_{A_k}(\omega_k)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}b-a-\frac1k$ there are infinitely many $m$'s such that $\mathbb{1}_{A_k}(\phi^m(\omega_k))=1$, i.e. $\phi^{m}(\omega_k)\in A_k$. Notice that $|\phi^m(x)-\phi^m(\omega_k)|=|x+m\theta-\omega_k-m\theta|=|x-\omega_k|<\frac1k$ and so, $\phi^{m}(x)\in[a,b)$.

Comment: Thank you! It's a lot clearer to me now after reading your answer.

Answer (score 3):

In this case $\varphi:[0,1[\to[0,1[$ is an irrational rotation.

1. Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem says that the time averages with *almost any* initial condition can be switched with space averages. Here the statement is that time time averages with *any* initial condition can be switched with space averages, that is, the exceptional set is truly empty. This is needed because Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem doesn't guarantee a priori that for the initial condition $0$ the statement holds, which is the content of the "number theoretic result" Weyl Equidistribution Theorem. (The fact that irrational rotations are uniquely ergodic is also relevant to this discussion; see [Topological Invariance of Unique Ergodicity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1149155/169085) .)
2. This has to do with $\varphi$ being length preserving, rather than measure preserving. If $\omega_k$ is within a $1/k$ distance to $x$, then for any $n$ $\varphi^n(\omega_k)$ will be within a $1/k$ distance to $\varphi^n(x)$.